# How can i change the background color of each items in listview?

Tags: android, database, listview, android-listview

I am new guy for android.

I done take my data from database and display it to the listview..

Now i want to set the background color for each item.

That is i retrive data from database, here one field is there, like status..

if the status is 1, then item color will be change to green.

like

[image: Display Listview]

How can i do this.

It is possible.      Please help me.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. You need to subclass an Adapter, and override `getView()`, `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()`

Answer (score 1):

In your ArrayAdapter you can check the value and change the View's background colour depending on the value.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the getView() method of your adapter, you can set the background resource based on the amount, as follows:

```
// assume view is your item view, status the number, and you have a context
if(status  == 1){
    view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
} else {
    view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
}
```

Now you need to make sure to define those colors in your resources by creating a file colors.xml with these contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="green">#00ff00</color>
</resources>
```

Note that if the items are clickable, it is important to provide feedback to the user when he clicks. In this case, you should use a [state list drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

---

Edit after comment. Your adapter should look like this, assuming that Item contains the name and status.

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private final Context context;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, Item[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.container = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.name.setText(getItem(position).name);
        holder.status.setText(getItem(position).status);

        Item item = getItem(position);
        if(item.status  == 1){
            holder.container.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        } else {
            holder.container.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        public TextView status;
        public LinearLayout container;
    }
}
```

Next, your list_item.xml layout should look like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/name" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/status" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am using this ArrayAdapter it is display only list_name and only one coloumn... how can i display listview with two coloumn..   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, db.getAll_CheckList_Name());// resource)
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    db.getAll_CheckList_Name().toString(), 10).show();
  l1.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of the adapter in which you can use a custom view, and how that view should look like in xml.

Comment: this part throw the error                                                holder.name.setText(getItem(position).name);
holder.status.setText(getItem(position).status);

Comment: I forgot to set the ViewHolder as a tag for the convertView in the if clause. (`convertView.setTag(holder);`). I updated the answer.

Comment: I can't remove this 2 errors  holder.name.setText(getItem(position).name); holder.status.setText(getItem(position).status);

Comment: Please give the brief explanation

Comment: name cannot be resolved or is not a field and it is same  for status..   and i dont know when i call the MyArrayAdapter class

Comment: Check if you have the ViewHolder class, and if it has the name field. If that seems correct, than you probably don't have the Item object set up. You need to pass some kind of object array to the adapter. These objects represent one list item each, and are obtained from the database. Make sure that this object has the correct fields like name and status (or make sure the fields you call in setText() are correct and exist in the object).

Comment: ViewHolder class is there. I don't know how can i pass the array values to that class

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact rules on Stackoverflow, but it might be handy to create a new question about how to pass results from a database to an ArrayAdapter, and show the code you use to get data from the database, because it is quite unrelated to this question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39921/discussion-between-selvam-and-jeffrey-klardie)

Answer (score 0):

This sample code can help you to understand basic approach how to work with listview and adapters.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private LayoutInflater m_inflater;
    private MyDataSource m_data;

    public ProfileListAdapter(MyDataSource _data)
    {
        m_inflater = m_activity.getLayoutInflater();
        m_data = _data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return m_data.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0)
    {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() 
    {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int _position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int _position, View _convertView, ViewGroup _parent)
    {
        View rowView = _convertView;

        if(rowView == null)
        {
            rowView = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_item_view, null);
        }

        if(m_data.m_list.get(_position).status == 0 )
        {
            View my_root_layout = v.findViewById(my_root_layout);
            my_root_layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_item_background);
        }   

        fillInTypeHead(rowView);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

For more detail information you could go to 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews

And I'll recommend to you watch this tutorial from Google engineers http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70
It's about basics in ListViews.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Model like

```
public class Status {

    private String label;
    private int status;

    public Status(String label, int status) {
        this.label = label;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

}
```

Create a ArryaList of Status

```
ArrayList<Status> listOfStatus=new ArrayList<Status>();
        listOfStatus.add(new Status("item1", 0));
        listOfStatus.add(new Status("item2", 0));
        listOfStatus.add(new Status("item3", 1));
        listOfStatus.add(new Status("item4", 1));
```

You need to pass the arrayList in your Adapter class. Now initialize ArrayList in Adapter class say **listOfStatus** and use it getView() method.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater lInflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.LIST_ITEM_LAYOUT, parent, false);
        }

        if (listOfStatus.get(position).getStatus()==1) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```